# Find possible paths with a recursive query

Tags: android, sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I've read [this useful article](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/sql-recursive-queries) related to SQL recursive queries. I want to do the same thing in Android and with SQLite. Here is the original query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_path (path_ids, length, is_visited) AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        ARRAY[node_id, destination_node_id], 
        link_length, 
        node_id = destination_node_id 
    FROM 
        node_links_view 

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        path_ids || d.destination_node_id, 
        f.length + d.link_length, 
        d.destination_node_id = ANY(f.path_ids) 
    FROM 
        node_links_view d, 
        search_path f 
    WHERE 
    f.path_ids[array_length(path_ids, 1)] = d.node_id 
    AND NOT f.is_visited 
) 
SELECT * FROM search_path 
WHERE path_ids[1] = 1 AND path_ids[array_length(path_ids, 1)] = 6 
ORDER BY length;
```

I am testing the query with [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) in Windows. But I get this error:

```
near "[array_length(path_ids, 1)]": syntax error:
```

I'm wondering what is the problem here and if `array_length` exists in SQLite?
If it doesn't how can I change the query in order to make it work in SQLite?

Comment: SQLite does not have array. Replace the array handling with another recursion.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Not all Android versions support CTEs; so you have to do this in Java.